# ansible: check whether few lines are in some file and add them if not

Tags: ansible

UPDATE QUESTION:

I am trying to validate that some function appears in .basrch file using ansible.

I have tried `lineinfile` module:

```
  vars:
    bashrc:
      - name: my_func
        lines:
        - "my_func() {"
        - "echo name=username\n}"
  tasks:
    - name: add my_func() to .bashrc
      lineinfile: "dest=~/.bashrc regexp=\"{{ item.1 }}\" line=\"{{ item.1 }}\""
      with_subelements:
      - bashrc
      - lines
```

But the problem is that every time I run this play, it appends those line:

```
...
my_func() {
echo name=username
}
my_func() {
echo name=username
}
EOF
```

I DON'T want these line to be appended if they already there

Comment: You need to elaborate your question. You need to explain what have you already tried to do, what doesn't work, what you don't understand, etc etc. 4 obscure lines or pseudo code are not very helpful.

Comment: I think you might be overcomplicating things for yourself. Is your function that you want to add to `.bashrc` THAT long that you can't compact it in 1 line? You might not need multiple lines for that, if you have a couple of statements in bash, terminate them with `;` and avoid multiple lines.

Comment: @mgsk I tried that too: `lineinfile: "dest=~/.bashrc regexp=\"{{ line }}\" line=\"{{ line }}\""` where `line: line: "my_func() { echo name=username; }"` but still the line is appended in every run.. :(

Comment: You have a lot of problems with quoting... let me update my answer.

Comment: See updated answer. hope this solves your problem eventually.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ansible has a module exactly for this purpose, it's called... `lineinfile`.

You will find documentation here: [Ansible - lineinfile](http://docs.ansible.com/lineinfile_module.html)

For multiple lines `replace` module is another option: [Ansible - replace](http://docs.ansible.com/replace_module.html)

```
$ cat myfile
this is my file
aaa
bb
c
foo bar baz
---
```

Task:

```
- hosts: all
  tasks:
    - name: replace something
      replace:
        dest=/home/vagrant/myfile
        regexp="^aaa\nbb\nc"
        replace="replaced some text"
```

After playbook run:

```
$ cat myfile 
this is my file
replaced some text
foo bar baz
---
```

I have never used this, but you might want to try `blockinfile`: https://github.com/yaegashi/ansible-role-blockinfile

**EDIT:**

This works perfectly fine:

```
- hosts: all
  sudo: false
  tasks:
    - name: ensure my_func
      lineinfile:
        dest="~/.bashrc"
        line="my_func() { echo name=username; }"
        state=present
```

`sudo: false` part is quite important. If you execute tasks with sudo then tilde (`~`) expands to `sudo_user` (root) home directory, otherwise it expands to user you SSHed as (`remote_user`)

If you have to do it for multiple users then try something like:

```
- hosts: all
  sudo: true
  tasks:
    - name: ensure my_func
      lineinfile:
        dest="/home/{{ item }}/.bashrc"
        line="my_func() { echo name=username; }"
        state=present
        owner={{ item }}
        mode=0644
      with_items:
        - user1
        - user2
```

Comment: lineinfile module is perfect for one line in file. I have failed to manipulate it to work for several lines. replace module doesn't have an option to skip if the lines already in the file.

Comment: I think you should clarify more what you need in your question. Also it has option to skip, you do it with proper regex. I don't see documented tries to solve problem by yourself either.

Comment: what is the proper regex to skip? add this to your solution and it's a bingo for me.

Comment: I would take a path of combining lineinfile & replace in multiple tasks, it all depends on the specific case. If not possible, maybe go for shell solution with UNIX tools. Again: show some effort and your tries.

Comment: @user1692261 if you are using `lineinfile` multiple times or other fussy workarounds, that's an indication you should be using `template`. Lineinfile is a bit of code smell in Ansible.

Comment: @tedder42 As far as I understand that `template` purpose is to generate a whole file. What I'm looking for is to modify (if needed) part of an existing file

Comment: @mgsk Thanks for your help mate. I have updated my question with (i hope) better explanation and one of my tries.

Comment: yes, it's meant to generate the whole file. Using `lineinfile` multiple times leads to headaches later- or immediately, as you've found. Generally if you need to use configuration management on part of a file, you can/should use it on a whole file.

Comment: Thank you. To sum up, if it is possible to compact to 1 line then `lineinfile` is the best tool. However, If I want to add a multiline block then I have to combine multiple tasks?

Comment: It really is case specific... Ansible doesn't provide a module to ensure block-of-lines-is-present in an easy way, you could do it with some shell magic also and multiple tasks. As @tedder42 suggested, `template` is the best way to go to simplify things.